# Convert xargs Bash command to PowerShell?

Tags: bash, powershell

I've got a simple Bash command to resize some images automatically on a low-traffic website using ImageMagick - I'd like to convert this to a PowerShell command so I don't have to install Cygwin on my webserver. Can anyone lend their PSh skills here?

```
ls | xargs -I {} rconvert "{}" -resize 128x128\> "{}"
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your best bet is to pipe the output of ls to the foreach-object commandlet like this (% is an alias for foreach-object):

```
ls | %{rconvert $_ -resize 128x128}
```

Edit: ls outputs a list of FileInfo or DirectoryInfo objects onto the pipeline. To filter out the DirectoryInfo objects, use the where-object filter (? is alias):

```
ls | ?{-not $_.PSIsContainer} | %{rconvert $_ -resize 128x128}
```

If you need to access the full path name in your command, use the FullName property of the FileInfo object ($_ by itself will be resolved to $_.Name which is just the filename):

```
ls | ?{-not $_.PSIsContainer} | %{rconvert $_.FullName -resize 128x128}
```

Comment: I think you should change $_ to $_.FullName

Comment: You're probably right, that's more robust, but the command is being run from the current working directory, so it should work.

Comment: You have an extra "{" in the second and third command that needs to be removed (before the "%").

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach cannot offer parallelism.