# How to run astyle over the list of files specified by git diff --name-only

Tags: git, shell, astyle

Running `git diff --name-only` gives me a list of files like this

```
file1
file2
```

Astyle usage goes something like this

```
astyle.exe --options=myoptionsfile <file1> <file2>
```

Instead of specifying each file manually I'd like a way to pipe the output of `git diff --name-only` as the list of files specified in the astyle program call.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also for Bash:

```
astyle.exe --options=myoptionsfile $(git diff --name-only)
```

`$()` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: `git diff --name-only` will return a multi-line output. In order for the above to work, one needs to translate from `f1\nf2` to `f1 f2`. Considering this runs on windows, with very inconsistent behavior between shells ... it may be a little challenging.

Comment: @azbarcea I mentioned `bash` and it does that automatically. Try `echo $(git diff --name-only)`

Answer (score 1):

What about using `Git Bash` or `cygwin` or any linux emulator on windows:

```sh
git diff --name-only | xargs astyle.exe --options=myoptionsfile
```

You can also do it [using `Powershell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794516/convert-xargs-bash-command-to-powershell).