# Convert xargs Bash command to Windows PowerShell for IPFS pinning

Tags: bash, powershell, ipfs

I'm not a specialist in IPFS and linux, but I'll try to describe a question as I can.
There is a txt file with lines, representing a list of filenames and its IPFS CIDs (I suppose).
The structure of the file is the following:

```
"description of a file" "IPFS CID"  
description1 CID1.....shnpnhzuquz3ho7vvabqjyide  
description2 CID2.....keg4rklbzenppnyrjk554h5ru
```

And there is a description, how to do it with a linux command, what supposedly pin of each line within this file to IPFS.

```
cat file.txt | xargs -L1 bash -c 'ipfs pin add $1'
```

How to do this command via Windows Powershell?

I've tried to enter the following (by the analogy of this question - [Convert xargs Bash command to PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/794516/21632448))

```
cat file.txt | %{ipfs pin add $_}
```

but it yields errors:

```
Error: invalid path "description1 CID1.....shnpnhzuquz3ho7vvabqjyide": selected encoding not supported  
Error: invalid path "description2 CID2.....keg4rklbzenppnyrjk554h5ru": selected encoding not supported  
.....
```

Comment: the following seem to be working:  

cat file.txt | %{ipfs pin add $_.split(" ")[1]}

Comment: seem that pins only first 10 entries :( still need help

Comment: Except for including the header line, the command in your first comment looks correct, and wouldn't explain why only 10 entries are processed.

Comment: Tangentially, that's a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 2):

*Update*:

- It turns out that the real input file has *no* header line, whereas his answer assumes that it does.
  I'm leaving the answer as-is, because the techniques of dealing with the header line may be of interest to future readers.

---

- Your input file has a header line, which needs to be skipped (your `bash` command would try to execute `ipfs pin add` with the word `of` from the header).
- From each line, the second space-separated token must be extracted and passed to `ipfs pin add`, which is what `xargs -L1` in combination with `bash -c '... $1'` *implicitly* does.

```bash
cat file.txt | 
  select -Skip 1 | # skip header line
  % {              # process each line
    ipfs pin add (-split $_)[1]  # Extract 2nd whitespace-separated token
  }
```

Note:

- On Windows, `cat` is a built-in *alias* for PowerShel's [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet, on Unix-like platforms it refers to the standard utility, `/bin/cat`.
- `select` is a built-in alias for [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), and, with lines of text as input,
  `Select-Object -Skip 1` is equivalent to `tail -n +2`
- `%` is a built-in alias for [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), which processes each input object via a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), inside of which the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) refers to the input object at hand.
- The unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) is used to split each line into whitespace-separated tokens, and `[1]` extracts the 2nd token from the resulting array.

  - An alternative is to use the `.Split()` .NET string *method*, as shown in a comment you made on your own question: in the case at hand, `$_.Split(" ")[1]` is equivalent to `(-split $_)[1]`
  - However, in general the `-split` *operator* is more versatile and PowerShell-idiomatic - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) for background information.

Note: I'm not familiar with `ipfs`, but note that the [docs for `ipfs pin add`](https://docs.ipfs.tech/reference/kubo/cli/#ipfs-pin-add) only talk about passing *paths* as arguments, not CIDs - it is [`ipfs pin remote add`](https://docs.ipfs.tech/reference/kubo/cli/#ipfs-pin-remote-add) that supports CIDs.

---

An **alternative approach** is to treat your input file as a (space-)delimited file and parse it into objects with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), which allows you to extract column values by column name:

```bash
Import-Csv -Delimiter ' ' file.txt | 
  ForEach-Object {
    ipfs pin add $_.'IPFS CID'
  }
```

Since **`ipfs pin add` supports *multiple* arguments**, you can simplify and speed up the command as follows, **using only *one* `ipfs pin add` call**:

```bash
ipfs pin add (Import-Csv -Delimiter ' ' file.txt).'IPFS CID'
```

This takes advantage of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature and PowerShell's ability to translate an *array* of values into *individual arguments* when calling an external utility.

Note that, at least hypothetically, there's a platform-specific limit on the length of a command line that you could run into (which is something that only `xargs` would handle automatically, by partitioning the arguments into as few calls as necessary).

Answer (score 1):

instead of trying to do this on powershell, use powershell to go to WSL, setup IPFS (Kubo for Go using the linux guide) and use this command to pin the files. remove the header on your first line manually.

```
$ cat /mnt/pathtoyourfile/file.txt | shuf | xargs -P8 -L1 bash -c 'timeout 2m ipfs pin add $1
```

one thing to note: your repo may not be in the default location, and windows env variables dont carry into WSL, so add your path to .bashrc by using

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

add the export command

```
$ export IPFS_PATH=/mnt/d/yourIPFSrepo/.ipfs
```

esc, and type :wq and enter to save and exit. use

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

to load it to current powershell for changes to take effect immediately. use ipfs init to check node initialization location. launch another powershell bash window to verify path is always changed to your specified path on launch.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (Fence your code with `\`\`\`` lines.)

Answer (score 0):

It started hanging after pinning 10 because of entry #11. I deleted 5 entries before entry #11, which now makes it entry #6. The code pinned 5 entries before hanging and was hanging on 6. I'm not sure what causes it to hang on specific entries though, but this code worked perfectly in powershell:

```
cat file.txt | %{ipfs pin add $_.split(" ")[1]}
```

Comment: You're speaking as if you're the author of the question, but your user account is different. Did you create a second account?
Note that the information about hanging isn't even part of the question, and the sample input data wouldn't explain it.
Unless you have specific information to share about the nature of a line that causes a hang, this information isn't useful to future readers.
By contrast, what _is_ problematic about the sample input data in the question is the presence of a _header line_, which your command
doesn't account for.

Comment: not author, but i know the file they were using to pin the items. since i am new here, they didnt let me comment on the comment section there. i was talking about the authors comment:
"the following seem to be working: cat file.txt | %{ipfs pin add $_.split(" ")[1]}
seem that pins only first 10 entries :( still need help".

the header line  is not accounted for, could delete that manually. also, no i dont know why it hangs, just know that the hang is because of the entry itself. hopefully someone more knowledgeable can shed light on it

Comment: I see, but without seeing the data, no one will be able to shed light on this. Turns out there was no header line, but if there were, there's no need to remove it manually, as  there's a trivial programmatic solution in PowerShell; a header line could even be leveraged for a more concise, OO solution.

Answer (score 0):

I need to clarify, there is no header in the file. So I edited the initial command.
For now, there are two commands that both work good:
1:

```
Get-Content file.txt | 
    ForEach-Object {
      ipfs pin add (-split $_)[1]  # Extract 2nd whitespace-separated token
      }
```

and 2:

```
cat file.txt | %{ipfs pin add $_.split(" ")[1]}
```

I think there is the problem in pinning particular lines. And accidentally it was 11th line. anonymouspanda is another user that faced the same problem as me I suppose.

Comment: I've since updated my answer to use `cat` instead of `Get-Content` and `%` instead of `ForEach-Object`, so as not to create a distraction, but I explain how they're _aliases_. Therefore, the only effective difference -between the two commands - albeit resulting in the same behavior - is `(-split $_)[1] ` vs. `$_.split(" ")[1]}`, and I've updated my answer to explain why you may prefer the former.

Comment: However, I've left the header-line handling in the answer, as it may be of interest to future readers. The header-line confusion illustrates the importance of providing _representative_ sample input and [formatting posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), to clearly show which parts are descriptive, and which parts are part of the data, as well as to show code with proper formatting.